# NSTextfield placeholder border removal

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstextfield

when nstextfield is tapped, makes placeholder text go up and how to avoid blue border highlighted?

without highlight https://www.sendspace.com/file/wjk0w6

with highlight https://www.sendspace.com/file/m8x6zo

I am struggling to find any solution since long time.

Any help would be a boon and highly appreciated.

Comment: What have you done to configure the text field's appearance? Set its font? Subclassed and overridden drawing methods? Something else? In any case, the issue is because the field editor is a different view from the non-focused text field. So, some customizations do not automatically affect that view. (Disabling the focus ring is easy, though. In IB, in the attributes inspector, set Focus Ring to None. Or set `focusRingType` to `NSFocusRingTypeNone`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, setting focusRingType to none did the job

Comment: For NSSecureTextField it does not works, any help for that?

Comment: I'm not sure. You didn't answer my questions. Are you only asking about the focus ring? Or also about the shifting of the text and the change of its font?

Comment: I did this for both nstextfield and securetextfield  
     NSColor *color = RGB(128, 128, 128);
    [[textfield cell] setPlaceholderString:text];
    
    color = RGB(128, 128, 128);
    [textfield setTextColor:color];
    
    [textfield setFocusRingType:NSFocusRingTypeNone];
    
    NSFont *font=[NSFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Light" size:15];
    
    [textfield setFont:font]

the url https://www.sendspace.com/file/wcef23 with same origin and height, but with secure textfield it stays bit up than was expected

Comment: After you set the font, try calling `-sizeToFit` on it. I suspect the text field is no longer the right size for the font and that results in the shift when the field editor is active. If you're using auto layout, then you would have to make sure your constraints allow the text field to be its intrinsic size, instead.